# ASP.NET Core 1.0 custom compression middleware and static files issue

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx, asp.net-core-1.0

My startup's middleware configuration looks something like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCompression();
    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
    app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();
}
```

Since adding the `app.UseCompression()` middleware, static html files in `wwwroot` aren't loading correctly anymore. **They don't resolve and tend to load indefinitely.**

The compression middleware looks as follows and was sourced from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1042980/Enabling-GZip-Compression-in-ASP-NET):

```
public class CompressionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate nextDelegate;

    public CompressionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        nextDelegate = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var acceptEncoding = httpContext.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
        //Checking that we have been given the correct header before moving forward
        if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding)))
        {
            //Checking that it is gzip
            if (acceptEncoding.ToString().IndexOf("gzip", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var stream = httpContext.Response.Body;
                    httpContext.Response.Body = memoryStream;
                    await nextDelegate(httpContext);
                    using (var compressedStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
                    {
                        httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", new string[] { "gzip" });
                        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(compressedStream);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await nextDelegate(httpContext);
            }
        }
        //If we have are given to Accept Encoding header or it is blank
        else
        {
            await nextDelegate(httpContext);
        }

    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Note: I am using DNX `1.0.0-rc1-update1` and the `1.0.0-rc1-final` libraries.

Comment: Did you try putting `app.UseCompression();`  as the last instruction? Registration (`.AddXXX` calls)  and usings (`UseXXX` calls) order does matter as it determines in which order the middlewares are called and if a later middleware overrides the demepdencies of a previous one (or requires it to work)

Answer (score 1):

I just enabled compression in web.config in /wwwroot folder (like we used to do in IIs applicationHost.config), and it works. There's no need to add a compression middleware.

http://www.brandonmartinez.com/2015/08/20/enable-gzip-compression-for-azure-web-apps/

Comment: This worked for me with no middleware needed (asp.net core 1)

Answer (score 1):

Compression defined in web.config only works with IIS NOT the self hosted web server.

I tested the `CompressionMiddleware` example and the problem You are seeing is caused by the **Content-Length** header.

If the **Content-Length** is already set, the browser gets confused as the actual size of the response doesn't match the value defined in the header as the content is zipped.

Removing the content-length header solved the problem:

```
httpContext.Response.Headers.Remove("Content-Length");    
httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", new string[] { "gzip" });
```

...even better you could try to specify the actual content-length when the content is zipped.

Comment: In fact you should specify the correct content-length after compression, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38274294/11220