# ASP.NET Core Compression Middleware - Empty Reponse

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am using some custom compression middleware [from this repository](https://gist.github.com/RossMerr/bb9163703370b4059733) (pasted below). Upon the first request, the content is compressed just fine. For every request after that, the response comes back as completely empty (with a Content-Length of 0).

This only started happening after migrating from ASP.NET Core RC2 to RTM.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

**CompressionMiddleware:**

```
public class CompressionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CompressionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (IsGZipSupported(context))
        {
            string acceptEncoding = context.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];

            var buffer = new MemoryStream();
            var stream = context.Response.Body;
            context.Response.Body = buffer;
            await _next(context);

            if (acceptEncoding.Contains("gzip"))
            {
                var gstream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", new[] { "gzip" });
                buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                await buffer.CopyToAsync(gstream);
                gstream.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                var gstream = new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", new[] { "deflate" });
                buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                await buffer.CopyToAsync(gstream);
                gstream.Dispose();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
    }

    public bool IsGZipSupported(HttpContext context)
    {
        string acceptEncoding = context.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding) &&
               (acceptEncoding.Contains("gzip") || acceptEncoding.Contains("deflate"));
    }
}
```

Comment: not actually sure that this is related to problem, but why you do not  close buffer stream in the end?

Comment: @Set: The following is thrown; An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. System.ArgumentException: The base stream is not writeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the following in "[Add HTTP compression middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/issues/34)" issue:

*I have added gzip and it worked, but first request. I mean in the first request, the response page is null (context.Response.Body) but when you refresh the page (just once) it works correctly after that.(I don't know why but I have to solve it)*

And response on question is:

> You need to update
>   context.Response.Headers["Content-Length"] with actual compressed
>   buffer length.
>
> [CompressionMiddleware.cs](https://gist.github.com/AndreiGorlov/388745f59145209fa951)

And above link to realisation of compression middleware contains:

```
if (context.Response.Headers["Content-Length"].Count > 0)
{
   context.Response.Headers["Content-Length"] = compressed.Length.ToString();
}
```